# location of struct ifnet on AIX

Tags: networking, aix

In which header file on AIX struct ifnet is defined? I want to use this structure to get network interface information on AIX.

Answer (score 0):

```
/usr/include/net/if.h
```

It is part of bos.adt.include.  You probably want to install anything with "adt" in the lpp name to get includes files and other things needed for building on AIX.

If you are new to AIX networking, you need to understand the `ndd` structure `/usr/include/sys/ndd.h` which is a per network device driver structure.  'ifnet' is a per interface structure.